# Ajax php array data loading all in one div and has commas

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, ajax

this is my first time working with ajax in the new world lol.. Its been a very long time since i have seen it and it has changed..

The problem i am having is that the data is all ending up in one div instead of accross the page in three divs.  If i load the divs manually it comes out fine, but when i switch to ajax its all in one div and the data is comma seperated as well.  I think it might have something to do with the way i am handling the array. But i have no experience in ajax working with arrays this way.

The comma seperated data is all ending up in the first div and i dont need the commas either.

here is the array (the first two elements i combine in the first div - name image)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => testprofile
        [1] => http://www.example.com/dirname/dirname/dirname/images/no-avatar.png
        [2] => adad
        [3] => 02:32:08
    )

)
```

here are the html divs

```
 <td align="center" width="20%"><div id="userdata"></div></td>
 <td width="70%"><div id="mesdata"></div></td>
 <td align="center" width="10%"><div id="timedata"></div></td>
```

here is the ajax

```
function ajaxGetMessages(roomid, urlwithr)
{   
 $.ajax({
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'GET',
  url: urlwithr,
  data: {
         roomid: roomid,
         urlrnd: urlwithr,
         ajax: true
        },
  success: function(data) {

   data.forEach(function(entry) {    

     var alphaname = data[0];
     var avatar = data[1];
     var displayuser = alphaname+'&nbsp;<img src="'+avatar+'" alt="avatar" height="30" width="30" />';

     document.getElementById("userdata").innerHTML = displayuser;
     document.getElementById("mesdata").innerHTML = data[2];
     document.getElementById("timedata").innerHTML = data[3];

    });//close forEach

  }//close success
 }); //close ajax

 }//close function
```

Comment: I think what you want is `entry[0]`, `entry[1]`, etc. Not `data[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array of arrays. And you're looping over those arrays with `forEach`. `function(entry)` provides each sub-array to the function procedure by assigning it to the variable `entry`, therefore access each item within the sub-array using `entry[0]`, `entry[1]`, etc.

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {    

  var alphaname = entry[0];
  var avatar = entry[1];
  var displayuser = alphaname+'&nbsp;<img src="'+avatar+'" alt="avatar" height="30" width="30" />';

  document.getElementById("userdata").innerHTML = displayuser;
  document.getElementById("mesdata").innerHTML = entry[2];
  document.getElementById("timedata").innerHTML = entry[3];

});//close forEach
```

Comment: Thanks so much i didnt even consider that lol  I guess thats like saying in php foreach $row as $value   thanks so much it seems to be working.. and no errors

Comment: And for anyone looking for a chat room script thats the guts of it.  The rest is just passing to the db which is easy, but it took me 2 days to figure out the ajax version to actually get the data back and process it lol...  So i hope this helps someone.  Everything else you have to do is easy... :)